# Why is my Idris FFI function not printing the value in REPL?

Tags: c, ffi, read-eval-print-loop, idris

I'm trying to print the result of an `add` function implemented in C as per [the docs](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ffi/ffi.html#ffi-example). I have

```
%foreign "C:add,mylib"
add : Int -> Int -> Int
```

with

```c
int add(int x, int y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

but in the REPL I get

```
> 1 + 2   
3
> add 1 2
add 1 2
> :exec printLn $ add 1 2
3
```

Why is Idris treating my function differently to `(+)`? Indeed, if I just use

```
add : Int -> Int -> Int
add = (+)
```

I get the same behaviour for `(+)` and `add`, from which I surmise it's sth to do with the FFI.

Comment: Idris doesn’t support it yet

Comment: @michaelmesser ok, thanks. Specifically ffi in the REPL?